# Hive: Filtering rows based on a range of Time

Tags: hive

I am new to this forum and this is my first question. i did search for solution on this forum but still unable to get the exact solution. If such a type of question is already answered then my apologies in advance.

Now coming back to my problem. I have a HIVE table "table1" having following columns:

```
channel_name     string
start_time       string
prog_name        string
cost             double
```

Below is the sample date from the above table:

```
BBC      2016-11-24 05:47:02     NEW: Wonder World       191.0
GTV      2016-11-24 21:35:58     NEW: Great Escape       99.0
BBC      2016-11-25 21:43:29     NEW: Wonder World       131.0
GTV      2016-11-25 23:32:56     NEW: STATE OF FEAR      145.0
GTV      2016-11-26 01:30:30     NEW: Great Escape       128.0
```

I have to find out cost based on filters on UI where user can filter by program name and a range of time from buckets of 0-5, 6-10, 11-15...19-24 etc. I developed below HIVE query where each row should be selected based on the program and the buckets of time filtered by the user. I have to compare on the time part of the entire timestamp value irrespective of the date.

Below is the HIVE query I tried but it is unable to compare and giving error:

```
SELECT sum(cost)
  FROM table1
  WHERE prog_name='NEW: Wonder World'
  AND (cast(substr(start_time, 12) AS TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN (00:00:00
                                                          AND 05:59:59)
       OR cast(substr(start_time, 12) AS TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN (06:00:00
                                                             AND 09:59:59));
```

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:118 cannot recognize input near ':' '00'
>   ':' in expression specification

What is the correct syntax to convert and compare only the time part from the timestamp value? Appreciate any suggestions/pointers for the above query.

Comment: The time intervals make no sense.

Comment: There are total 5 buckets representing 24 hours i.e. '0-6','6-10','10-14','14-19','19-24'. For finding the cost, date is not considered but only time. Thus if start_time for the program "New: Wonder World" is '2016-09-08 12:46:25' and '2016-09-07 21:48:49', both will be considered in the buckets '10-14' and '19-24'. Accordingly the where clause will be substr(start_time, 12) between '10:00:00' and '14:59:59' or substr(start_time, 12) between '19:00:00' and '23:59:59')

Comment: The `OR` is combined from two conditions that acctually create a single interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  sum(cost)   as sum_cost

from    table1 

where   prog_name='NEW: Wonder World' 
    and substr(start_time,12) between '00:00:00' and '09:59:59'
;
```

---

```
+-----------+
| sum_cost  |
+-----------+
| 191       |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks man! It works :) just a simple missing single quote and extra round brackets was the problem. And also, we do not even need to cast String to Timestamp data type, HIVE internally does it. This was a great help and saved lot of my time. Other wise I was planning to use case statement to group the rows into each bucket and use a subquery.

Comment: So the below query will give me all the results for entire 24 hours without taking date into consideration, right?

select  sum(cost)   as sum_cost

from    table1 

where   prog_name='NEW: Wonder World' 
    
 and 

 (substr(start_time, 12) between '00:00:00' and '05:59:59' or substr(start_time, 12) between '06:00:00' and '09:59:59' or substr(start_time, 12) between '10:00:00' and '14:59:59' or substr(start_time, 12) between '15:00:00' and '18:59:59' or substr(start_time, 12) between '19:00:00' and '23:59:59');